# Array, find object with value and get its indexPath

Tags: iphone, arrays, find, nsindexpath

I am trying to find an item in a `NSMutableArray` from it's value, only to find its indexPath.

I have absolutely no idea of how to do this, as I am very new to programming in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for [`- indexOfObject:`](http://file:///Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_2.iPhoneLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDHGFB)? This method returns the index on which the object specified can be found in the `NSArray` (from which `NSMutableArray` inherits) on which the method is ran.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. But how do I find the object? All I got is its contents..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BAJJDBEB)  or [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDHGFB)

Comment: A top level RTFM (by linking to an object's doc's) is not helping here